# Network issue with Windows 7 - characters keep appearing in putty session

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, ssh, putty

I have searched for a solution to this problem on the internet for months, to no avail.

Whenever I use putty to SSH to a server from one of my Windows 7 machines (64bit, PRO), I am constantly seeing control characters appear as if typed in by my computer. I am not touching the keyboard. It's so bad that it will cause the session on some unix hosts to drop spontaneously, and also causes havok if I try and edit programs on the server. Basically it's a nightmare.

I have other machines on this network including an ipad, a mac and another windows 7 machine (32 bit). On those machines inside the same local network, I can connect to the same servers and never get any mystery control characters on the input.

I know it's something in the network stack on this one machine - a DLL or some other bit of software that's sitting between me and the server that's adding all these characters, but I've disabled all the usual culprits to no avail. Wireshark will show the characters appear, but does not give any hints as to how or why or where.

I'm wondering if anyone has seen similar behaviour and knows which program or driver might be the cause.

Comment: Some further info: I've been wanting to compare with some other SSH program on the PC to see if it's just Putty or something else as noted above. I do have X-ming on this machine, so am using it today to connect to the servers... and it's working perfectly. It's on and had a terminal window with no glitches for over an hour now. A Putty window, by comparison, gets glitches within a few minutes, and they never stop.

Comment: So for the moment it appears putty may be the problem on this machine. I'm going to try an OpenSSH client for Win7 or some other SSH client and see if it's OK.

Comment: Update: installed the latest putty (.67) and things appear to be much better. I was using .63 so maybe that was the final problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen this a lot of times, but not that often for SSH. For console connections it is most likely due to incorrect baud rate.

Something similar happens in the case of SSH, but not related to transmission rate, but compatibility. It can be character encoding or even encryption type incompatibility.

In the character problem case, which is the most common, you will have to inform the server of your locale information.

Practically, go to the **Translation menu** in Putty and select **UTF-8** for received data. It is most probably set to some ISO-locale version. If UTF does not work, try the other options, but usually this one works if you connect to linux machines.

Comment: I checked putty and translation is set for UTF-8 on this machine. It's the same settings on the machine that does this as well as on the machine that is OK.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the version of putty (.63) was the problem on this machine. Updating to .67 seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Nope. I was wrong. While X-ming can keep a session on this machine open for hours  and hours without any problem, even the newest Putty generates control characters frequently. I also experience "network caused connection to abort" with Putty, but not x-ming and not on any other machine on the network (even other win7 machines (32-bit) running putty). The only difference is this is a 64-bit win7.